# How does this java stream code [distinctByKey] executes and is it stateless?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to distinct a list by primary key, and why does `Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();` executes only once and `seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));` executes for every element in the list?
And is the method `distinctByKey` stateless?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new UserInfo(1, "a"));
    list.add(new UserInfo(2, "b"));
    list.add(new UserInfo(2, "c"));
    List<UserInfo> result = list.stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(userInfo -> userInfo.id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return (t) -> {
        return seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    };
}
```

Comment: `distinctByKey` only executes once because it is only called once, when you pass the result to `filter`. It's the `Predicate` (implemented by a lambda in your code) that gets executed for each element in the stream. And that's also why `Set<Object> seen = ...` only gets executed once, because it's in `distinctByKey` but **not** in the lambda. Which also means your `Predicate` is **not** stateless.

Comment: Both, the builtin `distinct()` and this `distinctByKey` are stateful. However, the latter depends on external state, as the Stream has no knowledge of the `ConcurrentHashMap`. As a consequence, the builtin `distinct()` will respect encounter order and pick the first one of duplicates, whereas this `distinctByKey` can not make such guaranty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinct by key you can use trick with wrapper. Java stream API does not provide way to distinct by custom rule, it relies in equals() and hashCode() methods of your class.

If we want to use custom distinction then we can create wrapper class where we can override given methods:

```
public class Sample {

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class UserInfo {
        private int id;
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class UserInfoWrapper {
        private UserInfo userInfo;

        public static UserInfoWrapper wrap(UserInfo userInfo) {
            return new UserInfoWrapper(userInfo);
        }

        public UserInfo unwrap() {
            return userInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            final UserInfoWrapper that = (UserInfoWrapper) o;
            return Objects.equals(userInfo.id, that.userInfo.id);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(userInfo.id);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new UserInfo(1, "a"));
        list.add(new UserInfo(2, "b"));
        list.add(new UserInfo(2, "c"));
        List<UserInfo> result = list.stream()
                .map(UserInfoWrapper::wrap)
                .distinct()
                .map(UserInfoWrapper::unwrap)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Sample.UserInfo(id=1, name=a), Sample.UserInfo(id=2, name=b)]
```

And it will be definitely pure stateless solution.

Comment: Wrapper is another way to distinct a collection of entity by key.

Comment: The method `Stream.distinct()` is a stateful intermediate operation.

Comment: Ah yes. Anyway there is no need to add custom states.